# Custom Ruby method not working on nil objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following customer Ruby method:

```
class Fixnum
  def utc_datetime
    Time.at(self).utc.to_datetime
  end
end
```

I would use it like so:

```
time = 1386592732
time.utc_datetime
```

The problem is when `time` is `nil`. When it's `nil`, it throws this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `utc_datetime' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I avoid the `NoMethodError`?

Another use case that makes it a bit harder to just call an `if` statement to check is it's sometimes used for things like this:

```
Article.create(account: 1, published_at: time.utc_datetime, title: 'Example')
```

Comment: Never call `utc_datetime` on nil, as the method never exists for that method.  Since self will never be nil, this is simple to do.  self will always be a Fixnum.  The issue here is perhaps time is a method as well as a variable?

Comment: You avoid it by not calling a method on a nil object, or you add the method to the nil object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time.try(:utc_datetime)` will try to call the method for you and will return either the return value of the call or `nil` if it didn't exist.

Comment: The andand gem neatly encapsulates this, and I find it reads easier, e.g., `time.andand.utc_datetime`

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Just check to see if the variable is valid.

```
time.utc_datetime if time
```

Comment: I'd love to not have to call `if time` everywhere I use `utc_datetime`

Comment: Welcome to programming! Either do it every time, or once and set a default value.

Comment: Set a default value for what? `time`?

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to test for variable nullity:

```
if !time.nil?
  time.utc_datetime
  # ...
end
```

But you could also use a begin/rescue block...

```
begin
  time.utc_datetime
  # ...
rescue NoMethodError => err
  # recovery code
end
```

Yet another approach is for `utc_datetime` to not be a method of `Fixnum`, so it will perform the check itself, eg:

```
def utc_datetime(time)
  if time.nil?
    nil # or whatever you need
  else
    Time.at(time).utc.to_datetime
  end
end
```

The worst, but funniest solution is to give nil a `utc_datetime` method:

```
def nil.utc_datetime
  # whatever
end
```

An even better solution is to ensure that the `time` variable always contains a `Fixnum` instance.
Give it a default value, and make sure only Fixnums are assigned to it during its lifetime.

Comment: You can also use `unless time.nil?`

Comment: @screenmutt Of course, but I have always found the use of `unless` counter-intuitive. The human mind has trouble with negative assertions :)

Comment: While your answers are correct, I prefer to use the "try" shortcut on my response above because it's much more concise

Comment: @JavierRamirez Probably a lot more overhead. Also, not the standard way.

Comment: @screenmutt It's pretty standard, although I prefer the andand gem.

Comment: The overhead will be most likely optimized automatically when processed by the interpreter, and as per the standard way, this is standard on Rails (not on plain ruby). The question is tagged as ruby on rails and there is an ActiveRecord model there, so I assumed we are talking about rails, and then try is quite standard there

Answer (score 1):

`nil.to_i` returns zero

convert time to integer before call utc_datetime

```
time.to_i.utc_datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as the comments of vgoff and Dave, what you need to do is not to call it on nil object. There is nothing wrong with the method.

Secondly, in the context of Rails, doing such is wrong. You don't need to set creation time manually. The field `created_at` will be created automatially, and at UTC time.

What you only need to do it

```
article.created_at.to_datetime
```